# Struts Jquery Ajax Success not being called

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts

My Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "DataDictionaryAjax.do",
      dataType: "xml",
      async: false,
    success:function(data){
      var form = data;
    }
});
```

My response is
xml

```
Content-Type:xml;charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 01 Apr 2013 18:45:29 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

The xml is quite long, but I have confirmed it to be well formed.

```
servletResponse.setContentType("xml");
        String xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" + Formdata;
        servletResponse.getWriter().print(xml);
        return null;
    }
```

My ajax success is not being fired.

Comment: can you try with `async: true`

Comment: I would also add an error handler and maybe a complete to see if anything is happening.